# Associating octonionic matrices

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, octonions

Is it possible for three square octonionic matrices to associate multiplicatively even though some or all of their entries do not? If so, is it possible to construct matrix groups in this way?

Comment: In a meaningful sense, most (all?) of the exceptional groups come from automorphisms of the octonions, but that's looking at automorphisms of a real algebra, so not an answer to your question.  But, in its current formulation, the second part of your question seems too broad to be the sort that fits on MO.

Comment: How so? It seems rather specific to me.

Comment: The meaningless answer is "yes, you can form matrix groups from octonionic matrices, as long as they satisfy the axioms of a group."  So presumably you're looking for *interesting* examples; and that's the question that I mean is too broad.  (Similarly, for your first question, I suspect that the answer is "yes", and a bare "yes" answer could be very boring: "here are three matrices."  But, if the answer is "no", then that is very interesting, so I don't comment on that outside of parentheses.)

Comment: But how do you know that sets of entrywise non-associating octonionic matrices can form groups?

Comment: Just consider matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&x\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Wojowu, good point!; but, in [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427758/associating-octonionic-matrices#comment1100118_427758) example, the elements that might not associate are never multiplied by one another when multiplying the matrices, which is presumably meant implicitly to be part of the question.  (And, of course, adding the identity to your matrices gives a group (assuming that what was meant was "under multiplication"), though, again, presumably not one of interest … part of why I think that this question is too broad, because one has to specify what "of interest" means!)

Comment: @Wojowu those matrices aren’t invertible, so they can’t generate a group.

Comment: @DanielSebald I was addressing the first part of the question, with an example I gave you already on two occasions before. Though as LSpice points out, you can get a group by considering instead $\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Well, that answers my question.